# How to connect to on-prem AD from Azure app

Tags: azure, active-directory, ldap, azure-functions

I am trying to integrate our on-prem AD with an Azure function app. I need to be able to get users and update them.

We have both Azure AD and on-prem AD which are synced via the Azure AD Connect, which syncs only one way (from AD to AAD). So I want to update users in the on-prem AD, which will sync to the Azure AD.
For this, I am using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, which works fine from my local machine.
However, it doesn't work in my Azure app.

We have set up a hybrid connection to the AD to have a gateway, but we haven't been able to make it work. We have also created a user which has read-rights to the domain.

Code:

```
public Principal GetPrincipalUser(string employeeID)
    {

        var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain:636", "username", "password");
        UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(context);
        qbeUser.Enabled = true;
        qbeUser.EmployeeId = employeeID;

        using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser))
        {
            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> result = searcher.FindAll();
            return result.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

The exception we keep getting is: "The server could not be contacted. The LDAP server is unavailable."

Any advice on how to connect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using a gateway to our AD along with the [Novell Directory Ldap NETStandard](https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard)

Comment: Hi Linlin, I facing same issue where i need to connect on-prem AD from Azure function and perform create group/user. Could you please give more detail on gateway part you did.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Hybrid Connections don't support LDAP, because it can require UDP.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Not sure what the Azure Function is doing but if you just need to reset the password or unlock the account you can look at Azure AD self-service password reset (SSPR).

Comment: The other option is to run this code on a domain joined VM...

Comment: We want to manage our users via the function, so both create and update them. If we do so in AAD, the changes won't sync to on-prem AD, as the sync is only from AAD-->AD. 
Thank you for your input!